# react native android release 0.57

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Recently upgraded react native from 0.55 to 0.57.

I normally build bundle then use android studio to release. I use to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

However since I upgraded, I am getting this error.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
```

I am getting Error: Duplicate resources for all my assets when I try to generate APK.

Comment: show full error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your android/app/src/main/res to see if there are multiple folders with `Drawablesxxxx`, delete all of them should fix the error